# Google maps API get location by IP

Tags: location, ip, maps

That code works perfectly for Latitude and Longitude format :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU&callback=myMap"></script>
<!--
To use this code on your website, get a free API key from Google.
Read more at: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_basic.asp
-->

</body>
</html>
```

I was wondering if there is any potability to get the location via IP DIRECTLY thru google-maps (without converting the IP to Latitude and Longitude)

Comment: What's the problem with converting it?

Comment: I know about a few free services to fetch the Latitude and Longitude from IP but that's a bit messy I prefer to get it directly from google (1 single request)